# jest.spyOn equivalent for jest.mock

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs, spy

Mock a whole module but retain original module logic. Similar to `jest.spyOn` default behaviour, where the original method is called.

Using `jest.mock` allows performing the assertions needed, but doesn't execute the original logic and sometimes I want that logic to be executed.
Using `jest.spyOn` allows assertion and can execute original logic, but only on named exports of the module, which is generally useful but not when the method is exported as default or like in the sample code below.

```js
// moduleToMock.js
function doSomething(..args) {...}

doSomething.myWay = function myWay(...args) {...}

module.exports = doSomething

// moduleUsingModuleToMock.js
const doSomething = require('moduleToMock')

function doManyThings() {
    doSomething(...)
    doSomething.myWay(...)
}

module.exports = {
    doManyThings,
}

// moduleUsingModuleToMock.test.js
// --
// some way to mock `moduleToMock` that still executes original logic
// --
const doSomething = require('moduleUsingModuleToMock')
it('correctly does many things', () => {
    doManyThings()
    expect(doSomething).toBeCalledWith(...)
    expect(doSomething.myWay).toBeCalledWith(...)
})
```

Maybe I missed something simple, but so far docs or google fu hasn't yielded any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This came up often enough that I just decided to write my own library for generating auto mocks of modules that keep the original implementation but can be overridden just like `jest.spyOn`.

[Jest Mock Module](https://npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-module)

```js
import * as mock from "jest-mock-module";
mock.extend(jest); // optionally extend jest to use the "jest.spy" syntax
jest.spy("src/moduleToMock"); // Placed before other imports like "jest.mock".

import moduleToMock from "src/moduleToMock";
import moduleToTest from "src/moduleToTest";

it("does a thing", () => {
  moduleToTest.callFunctionThatUsesModuleToMock();
  expect(moduleToMock.usedFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently doing it like this

```
jest.mock('./somepath', () => (
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(jest.requireActual('./somepath'))
      .map(([key, value]) => [key, jest.fn(value)])
  )
))
```

this makes the module retain the original implementation but since all the exports are wrapped in `jest.fn` they can now be mocked with a different implementation in each particular test

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to mock a module and spy on its methods. The reason is that jest really replace the module with the mock.

Comment: I don't think this executes the logic in the original module, it just provides a mocked interface. `jest.spyOn(module, 'methodName')` still executes the original logic of the method as well as provides a mock interface, I'm looking for a module level equivalent.

Comment: Sorry missed the part with executing the original logic